# Macro filtering pivot table through a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, inputbox, vba

I would like to build a VBA macro to have a cell, where I can type a string, start the macro which filters a pivot table from another sheet called PIVOT.

I do have a solution via Inputbox (see below), but I prefer using a cell.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim IdentificationNo As String
IdentificationNo = InputBox(Prompt:="Identification", Title:="ENTER IDENTIFICATION NUMBER")
    Sheets("PIVOT").PivotTables("PivotTable1") _
        .PivotFields("Identification #").CurrentPage = IdentificationNo

End Sub
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you are going to work a lot with `PivotTable`s, you should use objects like `Dim PvtTbl as PivotTable`, and other pivot-tables objects

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
IdentificationNo = InputBox(Prompt:="Identification", Title:="ENTER IDENTIFICATION NUMBER")
```

to

```
IdentificationNo = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

That will use the value from `Sheet1!A1` as the input, so change "Sheet1" and "A1" as needed.